# Что не так в маршрутизации?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток.

Что не так? Почему не могу обратиться к контроллерам в Ариесе по такому адресу `/NameArease/Home`. Контроллер Home присутствует.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "NameArease_default",
        "NameArease/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
         new[] { "MyProject.Web.Areas.NameArease.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает вот так:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "NameArease_default",
            "NameArease/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { area = "NameArease", controller = "ControllerName", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```